# How can we find the sum for each subset of array

Tags: java

I am trying to finding the sum of each in the below code in java.What changes should i have to made in this code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

class as {

    static void printSubsets(int set[]) {
        int n = set.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0) {
                    System.out.print(set[j] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int set[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
        printSubsets(set);
    }
}
```

Output of above code is:

```
1 
2     
1 2     
3     
1 3     
2 3     
1 2 3
```

I want To Multiply  each element of subset by its last number for e.g.

```
1*1=1    
2*2=4    
1*2+2*2=6    
3*3=9

likewise all elements
```

and  lastly generate sum of all these subset `1+4+6+9+..` and so on.

Above code also print null set and subset are in order.How this program can be edited to make changes such that it does'nt print null set and print random substring.

Comment: I'm not sure what "likewise all elements" means.  Can you show an example of that operation too?

Comment: it means all Substring produce as     1 *1=1   2*2=4  1*2+2*2=6    3*3=9 1*3+3*3=12   2*3+3*3=15     1*3+2*3+3*3=18  means every element is multiplied by last number     so finally output should be printed as sum    1+4+6+9+12+15+18=65

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you want to multiply all the elements with each other and print out each step of iteration with the result. Here you are:

```
static void printSubsets(int set[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<set.length; i++) {
        for (int j=i; j<set.length; j++) {
            int var = set[i] * set[j];
            sum += var;
            System.out.println("( " + set[i] + " * " + set[j] + " = " + var + " ) -> sum=" + sum);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("final sum=" + sum);
}
```

In case of input `[1,2,3]`, the sum is supposed to grow according my algorithm by:

> 1, 3, 6, 10, 16 up to 20

---

Just a note about `<<` shift operator which shifts a bit pattern to the left. Let's say that number `2` is understood as `10` in binary. Shifting this number by `2 << 4` will result `100000` in binary that is understood as `32` in decimal. I am not sure you really need this pattern.

Comment: I think he's saying he wants all subsets ("substrings").  Then he wants to multiply each element in each subset by the last element.  Since sets are not normally ordered, I have no idea really what is the "last" element.  Then he wants to take all of those products and sum them together.  I think.  Not sure really.  I wish people would learn that the reason we have mathematical languages is because English (and other natural languages) are often imprecise in this regard.